How to use screen space coordinate of the mouse to set a model position in game?
I'm trying to make a movement system in my game where you click the mouse and your model moves towards where you clicked on the landscape, my understanding is the normalized screen coords go from [-1,1] in both x and y directions and usually there's a perspective matrix which is to make things appear like they have depth by making vanishing points and a view matrix to move the camera and/or rotate it.
I've tried simple raymarching by
float map2(glm::vec3 x) {
    return std::max(x.y, 0.0f);
}
for (int i{ 0 }; i < 100000; i++) {
    float dt = map2(camera_position + camera_direction * d);
    d += dt;
    if (dt < 0.00001f || d>10000.0f)break;
}
model_world_position = camera_position+camera_direction*d;


which works but it's only where the camera is pointing at not where the mouse is, it's also only if the sign distance function of the landscape is p=y which is unrealistic and it's also very slow.
edit:
i rotated the ray direction before the raymarch to estimate the click position on the landscape, first about the camera up vector to account for horizontal mouse location then about camera right vector to account for the vertical mouse location, the angles are calculated from mouse location which ranges from -1,1 for both directions and using half the field of view to find the angle and the field of view scaled by the aspect ratio for the angle in the other direction
camera_direction = glm::rotate(camera_direction , mouse_x * -fov_rad/2.0f, camera_up);
camera_direction = glm::rotate(camera_direction , mouse_y*-fov_rad/2.0f*frame_height/frame_width, camera_right);

it works but it's not very accurate for some reason

Thanks for clarifying. Examples are fine & you can add that part back in (especially if your goal is to get a similar system in your own game). The issue was that initially it focused on other games & generally folks either don't know with certainty (since most of us didn't work on those specific games) or can't say (due to NDA issues) how those games implemented specific features. The edited version appears to be on topic & I've retracted my vote to close.
